# Solution Space of Schrodinger's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

We are given Hermitian operator of the form

$H(x) =(-\hbar^2/2m) \partial^2/\partial x^2 + V(x)$

(where $\hbar$ and $m$ are real constants) which has orthogonal eigenfunctions corresponding to a set of distinct real eigenvalues, whose size is finite or countably infinite.

We also are given

$-i\hbar\partial\Psi(x,t)/\partial t = H(x)\Psi(x,t)$

(Schrodinger’s Equation, of quantum mechanics, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$)

We wish to solve for $\Psi$. Also, $\Psi$ is restricted to be a “test function”, in the distribution theory sense.

I have been told that, if $\Psi$ is a solution to the above equation, it must lie in the function space spanned by a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of $H$. Is that mathematically provable to be always true,  sometimes true, or maybe just a postulate of QM so that, although it is not mathematically always true, we assume it is always true for physical systems?

Comment: It's more of a postulate of QM. Not all unbounded self adjoint operators have eigenvalues. QM assumes that you work with "nice" potentials.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for your response! So, for nice potentials, all solutions to the Schrodinger equation reside in the space that is spanned by a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of H? If that is so, could you please tell me how can that be proved?

Comment: I'm not sure it can really be proved in a way that is satisfactory. Check out Gallindo and Pascual though. It's the most rigorous treatment of QM that I've seen.

Comment: The equation is a linear one. Unless something weird happens ( see @CameronWilliams comment ), the 'general solution' is a linear combination of its eigenfunctions.

Comment: @FelixMarin But the 2nd derivative in H is not linear, so is the equation linear? Also, H has eigenfunctions, but what do you mean by the eigenfunctions of the equation?

Comment: @David Sorry. It must be 'eigenfunctions of $H$'.

Comment: @FelixMarin Here is a thought I just had: Suppose we say that, for a particular $H$, Schrodinger's equation has a particular solution space that we call $\Phi$. Suppose we only care about the subspace of $\Phi$ that is test functions, which we call $\Psi$. Suppose that we can show that $H$ is hermitian for every function in all of test function space, which includes $\Psi$. Then $\Psi$ is spanned by the eigenfunctions of $H$ and any solution to that version of Schrodinger's equation must lie in the function space spanned by a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of $H$

Comment: Another approach is that, for a given $H$, we have a solution space, $\Phi$, for Schrodinger's equation. However, we only care about the subspace, $\Psi$, of $\Phi$, where $H$ is hermitian. Then any function in $\Psi$ must lie in the function space spanned by a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of $H$. Ex: For the $\infty$ potential well, we seek solutions to Schrodinger's equation that form a space over which $H$, for the well, is hermitian. That solution space has basis functions that are those of a Fourier Series and $\Psi$ (wave function) is a periodic function with compact support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not looked into the case of $\mathbb{R}$, but I have looked into the case on $[0,\infty)$ (or $(-\infty,0]$). In the case on $[0,\infty)$, for example, the Sturm-Liouville operator $H$ with no singular points in $(0,\infty)$, where you have a possibe boundary condition at $0$ of the form
$$
                   \cos\alpha \psi(0)+\sin\alpha \psi'(0)=0,
$$
you can solve for the unique classical eigenfunctions $\psi_{\lambda}$ satisfying
\begin{align}
      \cos\alpha \psi_{\lambda}(0)+\sin\alpha \psi_{\lambda}'(0)&=0, \\
     -\sin\alpha \psi_{\lambda}(0)+\cos\alpha \psi_{\lambda}(0)&=1.
\end{align}
(These are classical ODE solutions that may lie in $L^2[0,\infty)$ for some $\lambda$, but generally do not unless $\lambda$ is in the discrete spectrum.)
When you do this, you find that there is a unique positive spectral density measure $\rho$ such that the following outer integral converges in $L^2[0,\infty)$:
$$
            f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x')\psi_{\lambda}(x')dx'\right) \psi_{\lambda}(x) d\rho(\lambda).
$$
There is a corresponding Plancherel identity,
$$
                \|f\|^2_{L^2[0,\infty)} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x')\varphi_{\lambda}(x')dx'\right|^2 d\rho(\lambda).
$$
In this setting it is true that the every function in $L^2[0,\infty)$ can be built up from the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. This case fits rather nicely with Dirac's formulation; it fact, Dirac probably borrowed much of his formalism from the results obtained for Sturm-Liouville Theory in the early part of the 20th century by Weyl and others.

I have not thoroughly looked into how to link the two results on each half-line, but it is my understanding this can be done (possibly with a $2\times 2$ matrix?). So I would say there is a sense in which this statement of yours is true: "I have been told that, if Ψ is a solution to the above equation, it must lie in the function space spanned by a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of H."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how do we know that all of the solutions to Schrodinger's equation, for a given $H$, must lie in $L^2$ (a Hilbert Space) and are therefore in the space spanned by the eigenfunctions of $H$? $H$ may be hermitian in $L^2$. but if there are solutions to the equation that are outside of $L^2$, $H$ may not be hermitian over that greater space...

Comment: @David : In general, they're not square-integrable. Just as the $e^{isx}$ solutions are not in $L^2$ for real $s$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the $\varphi_{\lambda}$ are not typically in $L^2$ on $[0,\infty)$; in general they are $L^2$ iff $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum. In general, the integrals over finite intervals of $\lambda$ give non-coherent wave packs that are in $L^2$ because of cancellations.